# how to interpret this c typedef

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

the origin c declaration is

```
void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

I could understand this statement declare a function call signal that takes an int and an pointer to a function as parameters and returns a pointer to a function. But the use of the typedef as follows is hard to understand:

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int);
Sigfunc *signal(int signo, Sigfunc *func);
```

If I replace the "Sigfunc" with "void (int)", I couldn't transform the second declaration to the first. How to interpret the typedef in a right way.

What'more , can I write the following code to get the equivalent declaration

```
typedef void (*p_Sigfunc)(int);
p_Sigfunc signal(int signo, p_Sigfunc func);
```

Comment: All three declarations are equivalent, if that's what you are asking. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of your uncertainty.

Comment: *"But the use of the typedef as follows is hard to understand"*. Do you really found the first version the easier to read?

Comment: *"If I replace the "Sigfunc" with "void (int)", I couldn't transform [..]"*. In the same way with simpler example: `typedef int* int_pointer;`, `const int_pointer` is not `const int*`/`int const*` but `int* const`.

Comment: It is not hard to read. It is rather a bit unorthodox. `Sigfunc` is *a funtion* while `Sigfunc*` is a pointer to a function. Function types are very useful and readable but they are poorly communicated by educators.

Answer (score 2):

##### Case 1

In the statement:

```
void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

The above is a declaration for a function named `signal` that has the following properties:

1. `signal` takes two parameters. The first parameter of `signal` is of type `int` and is named `signo`. The second parameter of `signal` is of type `void(*)(int)` and is named `func`. That is, `func` is a pointer to a function with one parameter of type `int` and return type of `void`.
2. `signal` has the return type `void (*)(int)`. That is the return type of `signal` is a pointer to a function that takes one parameter of type `int` and has return type of `void`.

To make this **more readable** we can use the placeholder type `auto` and `decltype` in C++11(as this question was originally tagged C++ also) as shown below:

```
//more readable
auto signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)) -> void(*)(int);
```

---

##### Case 2

Now lets look at the second case:

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int); //Sigfunc is a typedef for the function type void (int)
Sigfunc *signal(int signo, Sigfunc *func);
```

`SigFunc` is a `typedef` for the *function type* `void (int)`. Thus `Sigfunc*` is nothing but `void (*)(int)`. And since in this case the return type is specified as `Sigfunc*`, the return type is the same as `void (*)(int)`. Note that specifying the `*` is important here.

---

##### Case 3

Now lets look at case 3:

```
typedef void (*p_Sigfunc)(int); //p_Sigfunc is a typedef for void (*)(int)
p_Sigfunc   signal(int signo, p_Sigfunc func);
//--------^------------------------------------>no need for explicitly writing "*" here
```

Here `p_Sigfunc` is a `typedef` for `void (*)(int)`. Note in this case we don't need to the `*` because we already have `void (*)(int)` instead of `void (int)`.

All of these function declarations are equivalent.

Comment: @DavidRanieri The question was tagged `C++` originally. I am editing my answer to also add more C explanation for the `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down:

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int);
Sigfunc *signal(int signo, Sigfunc *func);
```

So two things - the `func` parameter is a *pointer* to `Sigfunc` and `signal` returns a pointer to `Sigfunc`.

Since `Sigfunc` is an alias for "function taking an `int` parameter and returning `void`", then `Sigfunc *` declares a *pointer* to a function taking an `int` parameter an returning `void`.  IOW:

```
Sigfunc  f == void f(int);
Sigfunc *p == void (*p)(int);
```

Thus,

```
Sigfunc *signal( int signo, Sigfunc *func ) ==
Sigfunc *signal( int signo, void (*func)(int)) ==
void (*signal( int signo, void (*func)(int) ))(int)
```

And yes, you can do

```
typedef void (*p_Sigfunc)(int);
p_Sigfunc signal( int signo, p_Sigfunc func );
```

But...

I am not a fan of hiding pointers (including function pointers) behind typedefs in general.  Pointer semantics are special, and unless you are willing to build an API that completely isolates pointer-ness (such that the user of the type doesn't have to be aware of it at all), don't hide them behind a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, to understand this.

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int);
```

This type says: a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.

```
typedef Sigfunc *Sigfunc2;
```

This type says: a pointer to a `Sigfunc`. And since `Sigfunc` is a function that takes an `int` and returns `void` then: this is a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`; which is, again:

```
typedef void (*Sigfunc2)(int);
```

This type says the same thing: a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.