# C++ function pointer at declaration and argument

Tags: c++, function, casting, function-pointers, first-class

I am confused about using C++ function pointers.

```
using fn_p1 = void(int);  // function pointer
using fn_p2 = void (*)(int);

void functional(fn_p1 f) {
    f(1);
}

void callback(int value){
    // do something
}

int main() {
    fn_p2 f = callback; //works
    fn_p1 f1 = static_cast<fn_p1>(f); //does not work
    fn_p1 f2 = callback; //does not work
    fn_p1 f2 = static_cast<fn_p1>(callback); //does not work

    functional(f);  // works, the argument is form of void(*)(int)
    f(1);           // works
    
    functional(*f);  // works, the argument is dereferenced, void(int)
    (*f)(1);         // works
    return 0;
}
```

I know there is no difference if you call a function pointer with `f(1)`, `(*f)(1)`, or `(*****f)(1)`.
I don't get how `functional(f);` works but `fn_p1 f1 = static_cast<fn_p1>(f);` and its variants can not since they define the function pointer as `using fn_p1 = void(int);`.
Could anyone explain how the function pointer works or how the compiler deals with it?

Comment: `fn_p2` is a pointer-type. But `fn_p1` is *not* a pointer-type, it's missing the important asterisk to make it a pointer.

Comment: See related/dupe: [how to interpret this typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73185170/how-to-interpret-this-c-typedef/73185246#73185246). Also refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most useful error that the IDE should give you is on the line `fn_p1 f2 = callback;`:

> Illegal initializer (only variables can be initialized) [illegal_initializer]

(This is the message I get from clangd.)

That means literally that an entity of type `void(int)` (or more in general `someReturnType(someArgTypes...)`) is not a variable.

Indeed, in C++ functions are not first class, which means that you can't pass them to function and don't get them in return from function; when you think you are successfully doing so, you're in reality passing or taking back function pointers.

In other words there's no such a thing in C++ as "a function value". Functions are not values that you can assign to.

When you write

```cpp
fn_p1 f2 = callback; // assuming using fn_p1 = void(int);
```

you are truly trying to create a variable of type `void(int)`. But such a thing doesn't exist, hence the error.

The `static_cast`s don't work for fundamentally the same reason.

---

As regards

```cpp
void functional(fn_p1 f) {
    f(1);
}
```

[function-to-(function)pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) decaying is happening. `f` is truly of type `fn_p1*`.

You can easily verify it by writing an invalid statement in `functional` in order to trigger a compiler error telling you what the type of `f` is, like this

```cpp
void functional(fn_p1 f) {
    int foo = f;
    f(1);
}
```

Clangd answers this

> Cannot initialize a variable of type '`int`' with an lvalue of type '`fn_p1 *`' (aka '`void (*)(int)`') [init_conversion_failed]

which indirectly tells you that `f` is of type `fn_p1*`, so you better write *that* instead of `fn_p1` as the type of the parameter of `functional`, at least for clarity (similarly to how you should prefer writing `T*` instead of `T[]` as a parameter type in a function taking a c-style array of `T`s).

---

If you truly want to assign functions to variables, you should look at [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), [`struct`s+`operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator), [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and the topic of [function objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) in general.